# Order number of installments based on expected_date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an installment of payment and this table(installment) have columns called number and expected_date

```
@payment.installments.each { |installment| installment.update(number:xxx) }
i tried something like this
```

for example: payment has 6 installments, i need to order each installment.number and update the number based on his expected date? DESC ORDER
Some tip?

Comment: `@payment.installments.order("expected_date ASC").update_all(number: X)`. 
You need to do ascending order, so the upcoming installment date will be the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this:

```
@payment.installments
  .order(:expected_date)
  .each_with_index { |installment, index| installment.update_column(:number, index) }
```